# How to update nested state properties in react using immutable way

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js, saga

I am trying to update children records based on api response in reducer. My current redux state is containing data in following format :

```
const container = {
  data: [
    {
      id: "5e58d7bc1bbc71000118c0dc",
      viewName: "Default",
      children: [
        {
          id: "5e58d7bc1bbc71000118c0dd",
          description: "child1",
          quantity: 10
        },
        {
          id: "5e58d7bc1bbc71000118c0ff",
          description: "child2",
          quantity: 20
        },
        {
          id: "5e58d7bc1bbc71000118c0gg",
          description: "child3",
          quantity: 30
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am getting child1 data from api in following format :

```
{
    id:"5e58d7bc1bbc71000118c0dd",
    description:"child1",
    quantity:20  // Quantity is updated 
}
```

How can i update quantity for child1 in correct way ?

I am using immutable package. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/immutable

Comment: It is difficult to understand your question, what do you want?

Comment: I want to update child1 data in state.

Comment: You tagged immutable.js, are you using this library or are you just referring to immutability in general? You also tagged redux, is this logic within a reducer? Please add some clarifying details, and if you have already made an attempt please include that as well. It will help people give you better answers.

Comment: I am using following package 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/immutable

Answer (score 1):

I honestly see no reason to use immutable.js, if you don't understand spread syntax or find it too verbose then you can use [this helper](https://gist.github.com/amsterdamharu/659bb39912096e74ba1c8c676948d5d9).

```js
const REMOVE = () => REMOVE;
const set = (object, path, callback) => {
  const setKey = (current, key, value) => {
    if (Array.isArray(current)) {
      return value === REMOVE
        ? current.filter((_, i) => key !== i)
        : current.map((c, i) => (i === key ? value : c));
    }
    return value === REMOVE
      ? Object.entries(current).reduce((result, [k, v]) => {
          if (k !== key) {
            result[k] = v;
          }
          return result;
        }, {})
      : { ...current, [key]: value };
  };
  const recur = (current, path) => {
    if (path.length === 1) {
      return setKey(
        current,
        path[0],
        callback(current[path[0]])
      );
    }
    return setKey(
      current,
      path[0],
      recur(current[path[0]], path.slice(1))
    );
  };
  return recur(object, path, callback);
};
const data = {
  name: [{ hello: 'world', stay: true }, 4],
  list: [1, 2, 3],
};
console.log(
  'setting nested value',
  set(data, ['name', 0, 'hello'], () => 'hello world')
    .name[0].hello
);
console.log(
  'doubling nested value',
  set(data, ['name', 1], x => x * 2).name[1]
);
console.log(
  'removing nested value',
  set(data, ['name', 0, 'hello'], REMOVE).name[0]
);
console.log(
  'adding to an array',
  set(data, ['list'], v => [...v, 4]).list
);
console.log(
  'mapping an array',
  set(data, ['list'], v => v.map(v => v * 8)).list
);
console.log(
  'data is not mutated',
  JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2)
);
```

You didn't post any code of how you save that data in state, did you use the immutable.js classes for it? If you did then say goodbye to redux dev tools and logging state to the console. Best to just leave it as data objects (serializable with JSON.stringify)

Comment: I very strongly agree that using immutable.js is unnecessary. Its a cool library, but like you mentioned it makes development a bit of a pain. My biggest complaint is that I think it confuses newer developers and doesn't force them to learn about how JS objects and arrays actually work.They don't have to learn how to update state without mutation, and then unknowingly mutate state in other places..

Comment: @BrianThompson Spread syntax gets verbose quickly, that's why I use that set function in some projects, it's based on [lodash set](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#set)